# Initialize static const data members of a class into a class

Tags: c++, static, constructor, constants, initializer-list

Suppose we have this at a header file:

```
class A
{
private:
     static const double x;
public:
    A(double given_x);
};

class B
{
private:
    static const double x;
    class A;
public:
     B(double x_given);
};
```

And we need to initialize the static const data member of class A during initialization.
I thought that passing the variable `x_given` with initializer list from the constructor of B class to A class would be ok, but I'm apparently wrong.

How can this be done?

Also, both classes *might* need to have the same datamember.

**Edit #1:**
I need to declare a const variable so as to ensure that it is not changed anywhere in the class member functions.
But this value is given at construction time.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking. A `static` member isn't initialised in a constructor.

Comment: @sftrabbit: I've added clarification for what I want to do.

Comment: It makes no sense to initialize a static member in a constructor.  It's static, it's already been initialized.

Comment: @EdS.: I've added clarification for what I need to do. So static might be wrong. I need it to be constant.

Answer (score 1):

A static member has static storage duration, so it doesn't wait until an object is created before it is initialized. When you have a `const` static member of integral type, you can initialise it right there and then in the class definition. However, since yours is of type `double`, you need to define it in a single translation unit (such as in your `A` class's implementation file):

```
const double A::x = 48151623.42;
```

Comment: I cannot do this `static const double x = 10.5;` I am getting that only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class.

Comment: But still, I need to initialize a constant variable at the construction of the object, the value of which I don't know before construction. How can I implement this?

Comment: @Chris Does each instance of the object have its own value for `x`?

Comment: Nope, they'll all have the same, it's for the movement of some parts, so it will be the same. I've found out how to do it, I shouldn't have declared it as static. It's a const datamember not a static const one. Thank you for your help sftrabbit!

Comment: @Chris: Think about what you're saying for a moment.  You want a *constant* value that is shared across all instances of your type.  At the same time, you want *each instance to initialize it*.  That makes no sense.  You initialize it once at the class level, not N times at the instance level.

Comment: @Chris As Ed S. says, this doesn't really make sense. You use a constructor every time you create an instance of an object. How can they all share a value but each of them initialise it in their constructor?

Comment: @EdS.: (and sftrabbit) It's a class composition I am facing: Class man, contains hand right, hand left, leg left, leg right. For the movement of the man (hands and legs) we need a dt constant data member (as in v = dx/dt). So both classes hand and leg must have it AND it mush be passed as an argument at the constructor of the Man class. This is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Chris: Then you want 4 constants and, depending on which limb you are addressing, one is used.  An enum would be better.

Comment: @EdS. But dt is same for every limb. I was thinking of defining a global constant variable, but I am trying to avoid it so as to not litter the global space.

Comment: @Chris: Then don't declare it globally, declare it as a static member of the class.